# Dataset in NJ, US

Tags: data, united-states

I need datasets in shapefile format including roadbed, building footprint and building roof height for Jersey City, NJ. I checked everywhere I could online. State, county and local GIS departments, as well as the Columbia Univ. link that comes up on Google. I contacted Sanborn too, they have the data, but are asking $4,000 for it and there is no way I can pay that amount. Can anyone help?

Comment: Roads should be pretty easy. You may need to search at the county level rather than specific city - for example http://www.state.nj.us/dep/gis/tgr2000shp.html is a possible source. Building footprints is going to be quite a bit harder, and accurate roof heights more so. That's very detailed data that isn't commonly available. Might look at http://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/geonetwork/srv/en/cu-gis.search?extended=&remote=&attrset=geo&siteId=CU-GIS&any=&title=sanborn&author=&abstract=&themekey=&relation=overlaps&region=&hitsPerPage=20 or https://njgin.state.nj.us/NJ_NJGINExplorer/index.jsp

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to describe where you have looked prior to posting your question, please?